# How to avoid printing the algorithm number in algorithm captions?

Tags: captions, algorithms, algorithm2e

I am using the `algorithm2e` package to write algorithms. However, when i write three algorithms one after another, the algorithms are automatically numbered 1,2 and 3 in the caption. I am using following code:

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \SetAlgoLined
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
 \eIf{understand}{
  go to next section\;
 current section becomes this one\;
 }{
 go back to the beginning of current section\;
 }
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}
```

I am getting the resulting algorithm to be 
[image]

The caption of algorithm mentions "Algorithm 3" if this package is used three times. I want that for every caption it just mentions "Algorithm" and not "Algorithm 3". How can it be done?

Comment: Related [How to customize the number in the caption of an algorithm in algorithm2e](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/62240/15717)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11):

If you're willing to use `\TitleOfAlgo` instead (which, for algorithms, is more flexible than `\caption` in many ways), then see [John Wickerson's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114901/21891).

Otherwise, if you really want to use `\caption` but remove algorithm numbering, simply insert `\renewcommand{\thealgocf}{}` in your preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report} 
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\renewcommand{\thealgocf}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \SetAlgoLined
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
 \eIf{understand}{
  go to next section\;
 current section becomes this one\;
 }{
 go back to the beginning of current section\;
 }
}
\caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \renewcommand{\thealgocf}{} works for me

Answer (score 2):

As texenthusiast has pointed out in [a comment below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114899/avoid-auto-indexing-of-algorithms/114901#comment253897_114901), you should use

```
\TitleOfAlgo{How to write algorithms}
```

rather than

```
\caption{How to write algorithms}
```

This makes algorithms *not* numbered by default. If you change your mind and *want* the algorithms to be numbered again, you should set the option `titlenumbered` option when you load the `algorithm2e` package. (`titlenotnumbered` is the default.) That is,

```
\usepackage[titlenumbered]{algorithm2e}
```

For more details, see page 20 of [the package documentation](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf).

Comment: `titlenotnumbered` is (default)  hence not needed to mention but should use `\TitleOfAlgo{How to write algorithms}` instead of `\caption{How to write algorithms}` to remove numbering.

Comment: This is not a solution for me, because I need the `\RestyleAlgo{boxruled}` style, which doesn't work as I want when using `\TitleOfAlgo`.

Comment: Is there a way to also remove the "Algorithm" and just have it be it's title?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumberedhidden,algo2e,resetcount,algochapter]{algorithm2e}
```

in place of

```
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
```