# I can't figure out why my ref is displaying question marks instead of a figure number regarding a float

Tags: cross-referencing, captions

```
Please see figure \ref{loginMock}.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \label{loginMock}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{loginIdea}
    \caption{Landing/Login Page Example}
\end{figure}
```

I am using TexShop and the `caption` package, and tried compiling twice, but still `??` shows up.

The warning I'm getting in the console is:

```
Package caption Warning: \label without proper \caption on input line 29.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `loginMock' on page 1 undefined on input line 24.
```

thanks!

Answer (score 154):

The `\label` should always be after `\caption`:

```
Please see figure \ref{loginMock}.

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=7cm]{loginIdea}
    \caption{Landing/Login Page Example}
    \label{loginMock}
\end{figure}
```

`\label` enables one to cross-reference a numbered "item"; the "item" can be a sectioning header, a figure, a table, or something else still. To know *which numbered item* to link to, `\label` consults a flag -- let's call it "the name of the most recently incremented counter variable" -- that is set by the low-level `\refstepcounter` macro. In the case of `figure` and `table` environments, the item's counter variables are incremented (via a call to `\refstepcounter`) whenever a `\caption` directive is issued.

So if you put `\label` before `\caption`, LaTeX cannot link the label to the counter variable (here: `figure`) that you have in mind. Instead, LaTeX links the label to whichever counter was incremented most recently via `\refstepcounter`. And, if no such variable was incremented previously in the document, LaTeX -- or, more precisely, the `caption` package, which you've loaded -- prints the warning message that you report.

Comment: I had always thought `\label` only needed to be the last entry in a figure, but I was caught out with a `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` pair. Thanks.