# algorithm2e: How to make cross-reference hyperlink navigate to the top of algorithm?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, algorithm2e

Considering this MWE, I found that the hyperlink of cross-reference `\Cref{algo1}` always navigates to the algorithm bottom where caption is printed when not loading `ruled` option.

My question is how to force cross-reference hyperlink navigate to the top of algorithm?

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\Crefname{algocf}{Algorithm}{Algorithms}

\begin{document}
    \Cref{algo1}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \begin{algorithm}
        Some\;
        Algorithm\;
        \caption{some caption}\label{algo1}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring a persistent *warning*, the following solution works by inserting a duplicate hyperlink destination at the top of the `ruled` caption's `pre`display:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref,cleveref}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\Crefname{algocf}{Algorithm}{Algorithms}

\makeatletter
\let\old@algocf@pre@ruled\@algocf@pre@ruled
\renewcommand{\@algocf@pre@ruled}{%
  \Hy@raisedlink{\hyper@anchorstart{algocf.\thealgocf}\hyper@anchorend}%
  \old@algocf@pre@ruled}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\Cref{algo1}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{algorithm}
  Some\;
  Algorithm\;
  \caption{some caption\label{algo1}}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, but I found that the counter of cross-reference has a number of `1`, while the algorithm environment prints a counter of value `2`. So, how can I reset the environment counter to be `1`? I tried your [previous solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62243/2288), but it didn't help.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: I see. I'll work on this later today.

Comment: I appreciate your help.

Comment: I found another issue; loading `hypcap` spoiled the navigation of figures cross-references to their tops as previously done by loading `caption` package. So, how can I fix this also for figure environment?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: The best I can come up with yields a persistent *warning* about a duplicate destination identifier. It ensures a correct hyperlink jump to the top of the algorithm, and you can ignore the warning. It also doesn't need [`hypcap`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hypcap) anymore.