# Prefix algorithm number with algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

When using the `algorithm` package it is possible to prefix algorithm numbers with a string (in this example `Cool.`) like so:

```
\renewcommand\thealgorithm{Cool.\arabic{algorithm}}
```

*(This works for a bunch of other elements as well as explained in detail at https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~paciorek/computingTips/Customizing_numbering_pages.html)*

The same setting does not work with the `algorithm2e` package. Is there another way to prefix algorithm numbers with `algorithm2e`?

**Update:** It's possible to provide a custom reference name using `\SetAlgoRefName{XYZ}` but that requires manual setting of every reference name. I am wondering if it's possible to automatically / globally prefix all algorithm numbers.

Comment: Can you post your complete MWE, please?

Comment: Section 9.2 of [`algorithm2e`](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm2e/doc/algorithm2e.pdf) documentation may help

Comment: @Sebastiano What does MWE stand for and what are you missing? I am trying to find out how to prefix algorithm numbers with a specific string so that `Algorithm 1:...` turns into `Algorithm Cool.1:...`.

Comment: @BambOo Thanks. `\SetAlgoRefName{}` works on a per algorithm basis but then I have to manually set every algorithm.

Comment: Did you try to define `\SetAlgoRefName{}` in your preamble ?

Comment: @BambOo It's not needed. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62243/132552), I found out `algorithm2e`'s correct `counter` name. The following allows customizing the enumeration of `algorithm2e` numbers:

```
\renewcommand{\thealgocf}{S\arabic{algocf}}
```

*I.e., the first algorithm's number is now `S1` instead of `1`*